# cURL equivalent in Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, curl

I've tried different things to create the swift equivalent of this cURL request, but I couldn't get it working.

```
curl -X POST -F "file=@/Users/nicolas/sample.png" -F "mode=document_photo" https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/sync/ocrdocument/v1 -F "apikey=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
```

The respective code is posted below.

```
func getText (image: UIImage){

    let apiKey = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/sync/ocrdocument/v1")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")
    request.addValue("document_photo", forHTTPHeaderField: "mode")
    request.HTTPBody = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1), completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in


        if let _ = data {
            var error:NSError? = nil
            do {
                let jsonObject : AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
                let json = JSON(jsonObject)
                if let ocr_results = json["text_block"][0]["text"].string {
                    self.returnText(ocr_results)
                }
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                print(error)
            } catch {
                fatalError()
            }
        }

})
```

I would be happy if I get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the curl command, you are defining the form fields `file`, `mode` and `apikey`, and you need to encode them in the form `multipart/form-data` and put this in the `HTTPBody`. Some quick googling reveals the library [SRWebClient](https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient) (among many others) that will help you make this sort of request.

Comment: What did you search to find this library? Because this library isn't working in swift 2.0, so I can search for another library that swirls with swift 2.0.

Comment: I searched for "multipart/form-data". Note that you can also use Objective-C libraries, of which there are many. Most HTTP request libraries are able to do this - if they say they support file uploads/sending, this is how that's accomplished.

Comment: And also, most libraries will take care of setting up the `NSURLRequest` entirely for you (so you don't, for example, get an `NSData` back that you have to assign to `HTTPBody`).

Comment: I'm trying to do it wit Alamofire, but I can't get it working, since it's my first time working with a api. Do you know how to do it with Alamofire? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834704/curl-with-alamofire-swift-multipart-form-data

Comment: I've never heard of Alamofire before now, but looking at its Github page I found an interesting section in the readme called [Uploading MultipartFormData](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-multipartformdata). The `mode` and `apikey` fields need to be added with appendBodyPart just as the file does, and it looks like it takes an NSData so you need to encode the string to UTF-8 or another encoding. But I'll let the Alamofire experts sort that out.