# cURL with Alamofire - Swift - multipart/form-data

Tags: swift, curl, multipartform-data, swift2, alamofire

First, im sorry if this question is stupid but im pretty new to this stuff. I've tried different things to create the swift equivalent of this cURL request with Alamofire, but I don't know how to send the image as a multipart/form-data to the API.

```
curl -X POST -F "file=@/Users/nicolas/sample.png" -F "mode=document_photo" https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/sync/ocrdocument/v1 -F "apikey=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
```

I think current code is pretty wrong for this type of request, but still i'm gonna post it for you:

```
func getOCR(image: UIImage) {

    let url = "https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/sync/ocrdocument/v1"
    let apiKey = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: ["apikey": apiKey, "file": imageData!]).responseJSON() {
        _,_,JSON in
        print(JSON)
    }
}
```

The only way how it worked for me until now, was using a URL, but since I try to send a image to the server that the user took with the camera, i only can send a image file.

URL Code:

```
func test(url: NSURL) {

    let url = "https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/sync/ocrdocument/v1"
    let apiKey = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"

    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: ["apikey": apiKey, "url": url]).responseJSON() {
        _,JSON,_ in
        print(JSON)
    }
}
```

I would be happy if I get a response, because this is driving me crazy.

ps. Im using swift 2.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alamofire has an example in their [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/1.3.0/index.html#user-content-uploading-multipartformdata) using `Alamofire.upload(_:URLString:headers:multipartFormData:encodingMemoryThreshold:encodingCompletion:)` that looks like it will answer your question (note that in their example, the `headers` and `encodingMemoryThreshold` parameters have a default value if you don't supply one).

Also see their documentation on the various `appendBodyPart()` methods on a [MultipartFormData](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/1.3.0/Classes/MultipartFormData.html) class instance.

So, a way in which your provided example code could be modified might be:

```
func getOCR(image: UIImage) {

  let url = "https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/sync/ocrdocument/v1"
  let apiKey = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
  let mode = "document_photo"
  let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

  Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    URLString: url,
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
      multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(
        data: apiKey.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
        name: "apikey"
      )
      multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(
        data: mode.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
        name: "mode"
      )
      multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(
        data: imageData!,
        name: "file",
        fileName: "testIMG.png",
        mimeType: "image/png"
      )
    },
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
      switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
          upload.responseJSON { _, _, JSON in println(JSON) }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
          println(encodingError)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok, the problem was the image, it worked with a different one, but now I get this error: `Alamofire.Result<Swift.AnyObject>.Success([error: 4001, detail: {
    expected = "\UfffdPNG
\n\n
IHDR\Ufffd\b\..................\Ufffd >@\Ufffd\UfffdIEND\UfffdB\Ufffd";
    found =     (
    );
}, reason: No file submitted])`

Comment: you may need to use one of the other `appendBodyPart()` methods on MultipartFormData (see the link in the answer) in order to set a MIME type - I just saw, too, that your original example includes an apiKey, you may need to add that to the request via another call to `appendBodyPart()` in the closure passed to the `multipartFormData` parameter of `upload()`

Comment: I've already added the apiKey and changed it to "file" but nothing worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85214/discussion-between-nmac427-and-fqdn).

Comment: okay - updated the example in the answer to be complete - this will be an awesome reference, thank you for working through it with me @NMAC427 !!